# Having a dynamic field without a workflow or event receiver

Tags: list, custom-list

To make things more clear: I have 2 lists, events and people.

I am creating, dynamically, a list that is supposed to take values from both lists. It's pretty simple but the complicated part is: the second field in the dynamically created list is determined by the value of the first field (which is a lookup field).

Basically, I need to populate a field after a certain field is populated.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to make use of the function `$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns` in SPServices jQuery library.

Here is the Codeplex website: http://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: Ok, maybe I wasn't that clear. I want it to be a UI job only. No code involved.